# xutility.h error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

Tags: c++, debugging, templates

I've question to ask.

I've created a class called AstarPlanlama and have these 2 functions:

```
bool AstarPlanlama::nodeComp(const Node* lhs, const Node* rhs) 
{
   return lhs->F < rhs->F;
}

void AstarPlanlama::enKucukFliNodeBul(std::list<Node*> * OPEN)
{
    std::list<Node*>::iterator it = std::min_element(OPEN->begin(), OPEN->end(), &AstarPlanlama::nodeComp);

    OPEN->sort(&AstarPlanlama::nodeComp);   

    Q = OPEN->front();      

    OPEN->pop_front();      
}
```

When I compile my code the error occurs in the **xutility.h** file.

```
template<class _Pr, class _Ty1, class _Ty2> inline
    bool _Debug_lt_pred(_Pr _Pred,
        _Ty1& _Left, _Ty2& _Right,
        _Dbfile_t _File, _Dbline_t _Line)
    {   // test if _Pred(_Left, _Right) and _Pred is strict weak ordering
    if (!_Pred(_Left, _Right))
        return (false);
    else if (_Pred(_Right, _Left))
        _DEBUG_ERROR2("invalid operator<", _File, _Line);
    return (true);
    }
```

Declerations of the functions:

```
    bool nodeComp(const Node* lhs, const Node* rhs);

    void enKucukFliNodeBul(std::list<Node*> * OPEN);
```

The error line is **if (!_Pred(_Left, _Right))**

What is wrong with the code?

Thank you for your returns..

My regards..

Comment: Can you show the declarations for the two functions? Also, names in all UPPERCASE are by convention used by the preprocessor. I would strongly recommend not to call anything OPEN as the name might conflict with a preprocessor macro and that leads to all sorts of fun debugging.

Comment: Look in the "Output" window. The full context of the error will be there, including which template instantiations in which files led to the error.

Comment: Member functions have an additional argument - `this`. Your member function in fact evaluates to a function taking **three** arguments, unless, of course, it's static.

Comment: @TimoGeusch I've added the declerations..

Comment: @chris I actually don't get what you mean?

Comment: @TimoGeusch Both answers are working, I don't know which to choose.

Comment: @Jesse Good Both answers are working, I don't know which to choose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are passing a member function as your custom comparator. 
Make it `static` or use `std::bind`:

```
 std::list<Node*>::iterator it = std::min_element(OPEN->begin(), OPEN->end(),
                                       std::bind(&AstarPlanlama::nodeComp, 
                                                 this,
                                                 std::placeholders::_1,
                                                 std::placeholders::_2));

OPEN->sort(std::bind(&AstarPlanlama::nodeComp, 
                     this,
                     std::placeholders::_1,
                     std::placeholders::_2));
```

Member functions are special and need to be called on an object, this is why `std::bind` is needed to bind to the `this` pointer.

Comment: I'm away from my PC now. I'm gonna give it a shoot and let you know if it works.

Comment: I think `std::mem_fn` works as well, but I keep forgetting how to use it. Also, I think the two placeholders are unnecessary. From what I remember, just doing `auto bound = std::bind(foo, bar); bound(1, 2);` will call `foo(bar, 1, 2);`.

Comment: @chris: `std::mem_fn` requires 3 arguments to be called, the first being a class object instance, so it cannot be used here. `std::placeholders` are used for the unbound arguments, they need to be used in the example. Try out the code and see what happens.

Comment: @Un_NatMenDim: Also, I would recommend using references instead of pointers, i.e. change `bool nodeComp(const Node* lhs, const Node* rhs);` to `bool nodeComp(const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs);` and the comparison to `return lhs.F < rhs.F;`, etc.

Comment: @JesseGood, Oh, that's right. `mem_fn` does that. I also could have sworn `bind` worked when you bound the first x arguments, but it seems I'm wrong there, too. I remember, vividly, not having to use placeholders for something, but then again, it could just be my memory backstabbing me again.

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration of `nodeComp()` is wrong - if you want to follow standard library conventions it needs to be either a free function or a static function, not a regular member function. Normally, I would recommend to make it a free function that's marked as a friend so it can gain access to private class members. The function as you declared it doesn't make the comparator function that's expected in xutility.h, as it carries the "hidden this" parameter, which is carried by all non-static member functions.

Also, given the implementation of `nodeComp()`, there is no reason at all to make it a regular member function as it doesn't operate on its object's data, but on the data of objects that are being passed in as parameters.

In order to simplify both your life and the life of whoever else has to maintain the code after you, I would follow the standard library convention and replace nodeComp() with the following code and declare the operator a friend inside the class declaration of AstarPlanlama.

```
bool operator<(const AstarPlanlama::Node* lhs, const AstarPlanlama::Node* rhs) 
{
  return lhs->F < rhs->F;
}
```

Also, it's generally a bad idea to put raw pointers into standard library containers as that can lead to all sorts of interesting lifetime management issues. If you absolutely have to use pointers, I would recommend either using a container that's designed for it like the boost pointer containers, or wrap the object in a `std::shared_ptr` instead of handling a raw pointer.

Comment: I'm away from my PC now. I'm gonna give it a shoot and let you know if it works.